# Unanswered Questions Recommender

Tags: app, questions

Put in your user id, get a list of recent unanswered questions that you'll be able to answer:

https://lateral.io/demos/stackoverflow-unanswered/

[image]

Comment: So could you tell us a little bit about how this works? It seems it matches me with questions that others that often answer the same questions as me has attempted to answer. I browsed the 15 questions it recommended me, but I was unfortunately unable to add additional information because they all had good answers already. I realize that if no one has attempted to answer the question it's hard to match that question to anyone though :-/